# Feature proposal: Easy linking to MDN documentation (and maybe other quality sources)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, help-center

In Stack Overflow Q&As on Web-platform technologies (JavaScript, Web APIs, CSS, HTML), it’s quite common to see users adding links to MDN content (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) as an authoritative source.
So might it be worthwhile to make it a bit easier for users to do that?

*(For more rationale on why MDN in particular is worth singling out in a feature, read further down.)*

As far as implementation, you can imagine something similar to the **Insert Link to Documentation** widget that before the SO Documentation expansion was sunsetted had appeared as an additional tab along with **Insert Hyperlink** in the pop-up shown if you click the edit bar’s [image] (link) button:

[image: “Link to Documentation” widget]

…except that this new widget would instead be titled **Insert Link to MDN Web Docs** (or such) and:

1. You type in a term and are then presented with list of MDN article titles to choose from.
2. You select an MDN article title from the list.
3. A Markdown-formatted link to the MDN article is inserted in your editing area.

Alternatively instead of **Insert Link to MDN Web Docs**, the **Insert Link to Documentation** general title could be resurrected, and the widget would enable easy linking to a number of external documentation sites. Implemented that way, within the widget there’d be an additional select control for choosing from among the available documentation sites before going through the steps above.

But regardless, as far as the MDN-specific part, a model for how that works is an existing widget MDN already provides in its own editing UI, which works like this: If you want to find, say, some specific CORS-related MDN article, the widget gives you a “lookup” box into which you type *`CORS`*, and then based on that lookup term, shows a list of article titles:

[image: MDN “insert link” widget]

Select *“CORS settings attributes [en-US]”* from that, push <kbd>OK</kbd>, and it inserts into the article some markup for a link with the relative URL `/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes`.

A similar widget at SO would insert a Markdown-formatted link with an absolute URL and link text auto-generated from the MDN article title plus boilerplate indicating it’s an MDN link; for example:

> *…blah blah*  [the MDN article “CORS settings attributes”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes)  *blah blah*

---

The lookup data can be retrieved as JSON from an existing endpoint that MDN already exposes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/get-documents?term=CORS

The structure of that data (in this case, the part for the main MDN “CORS” article), looks like this:

[image: JSON data]

Notice that also exposed in that data are the section titles — so it’d also be possible for a lookup widget to provide a way to create a link not only to the article titles, but also to specific sections:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests
```

---

Anyway, all of the preceding is the substance of the feature proposal. The rest of what follows is just an explanation about what makes MDN exceptional enough to inspire adding the feature.

---

#### Why the special focus on MDN?

Of course given the wide range of programming platforms covered in SO Q&As, others may also have related widely-used high-quality documentation sites that would merit easy linking. But a rationale for providing some easier linking to documentation on Web technologies specifically is that the Web platform covers a lot of ground as far as programming technologies go — to the point that a pretty significant subset of SO questions and answers relate to Web programming

And within the field of Web technologies, as far as what’s exceptional in particular about MDN:

- MDN content is relatively high-quality and accurate and up-to-date, especially in contrast to W3Schools (somewhat, MDN is to W3Schools as Stack Overflow is to Experts Exchange)
- MDN as a system has key characteristics (some of the best of which are similar to SO’s) around openness and enabling collaborative editing, and has a large, active community of contributors behind it who are the biggest force in keeping the site up-to-date and accurate
- MDN’s high level of quality is also due in part to Mozilla having a number of employees who work on MDN full-time (I think) — doing a range of task everywhere from writing content, to copy-editing/refining/fixing community contributions, to helping on-board new contributors
- MDN also benefits from Google and Microsoft paying employees to work on  contributing content — in particular, actively keeping up-to-date the MDN data about browser/browser-version support for particular features, but also writing MDN articles and more
- MDN, for those reasons and other others, has essentially become the *de facto* authoritative source for documentation on Web-platform technologies — to the degree it has unique value in a way similar to how Stack Overflow has unique value

Comment: -1: No free-hand red circles. Missed chance. (Good idea, me likes!)

Comment: Here's Microsoft's announcement from last October of their transition from MSDN web docs to MDN: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/10/18/documenting-web-together-mdn-web-docs/

Comment: I agree with MDN for web technologies, but what about python, perl, C...? I really like the concept, but there are also other authoritative references for other technologies.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn MDN’s just the particular external documentation source I’m personally most familiar with & that I’m confident the general mechanism behind what I proposed could be made to work with. So I wrote the above as MDN-specific because I wanted to make a feasible-to-implement concrete proposal rather than something hand-wavy or something so broad that it risked being seen as a “boil the ocean” idea. But I agree in principle that where there are existing external sources similar to MDN for other platforms/programming-environments, then the proposed mechanism could make sense for them too

Comment: In principle, this could be useful, but the difficulty is that the areas I work in don't use MDN. There are a number of sites that are widely used; some are more authoritative than others. How would SO (both as a corporation and as the members) choose which sites are authoritative, and how would the search work across a disparate set of sites? (For example, there's the POSIX standard, the C standard, the C and/or C++ 'reference' sites, the Linux C libraries (several sites competing), the BSD C libraries (multiple variants), MSDN, … There are problems assessing and choosing between them.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed on the problems in assessing. To help — and for practical reasons — maybe a criterion for inclusion would be whether the site exposes an API for programatic lookups similar to what MDN does. Because as proposed above, the MDN lookup would be executed 100% on the client/frontend side in a browser — with zero additional load on Stack Overflow infrastructure & with zero need for Stack Overflow to store any data for it on their backend, nor to scrape any data from the site. Any sites that don’t expose similar programmatic access to their docs would necessarily not included.

Comment: Good idea. My local PC is german, so when I google something, the MDN pages come up in [de-at] or [de-de] first. If I then proceed to include the link on a SO post, I usually manually replace [de-at] by [en-us]. Or forget about it, annoying future visitors. If this feature is implemented, it would be added value to convert the links into their language-invariant or [en-us] versions automatically.

Comment: I rather be able to put in the link description in the dialog that pops up when you press the link button.

Comment: I feel this would be far more useful of a tool if it could be used while commenting, as that's probably the place where it would be the most useful. If a question is asking something that's easily answered by an example and a link to MDN, there's a relatively high chance that it's already answered here and therefore the tool wouldn't be useful in those cases. (other than for providing duplicate answers)

Comment: mozilla.org MDN is blocked here

Comment: "enabling collaborative editing" really? On SO?

Comment: In my eyes, this would only lead us to an increase of one-line or link-only answers, where no further research or explanation into the *why* of a solution has been applied, devaluing in depth answers by folks like John Skeet, or his millioneth clone. While this is something that I feel should not be added, perhaps we could, where appliccable, point users - especially newcomers to MDN on the Ask a Question page. This way, we could also increase their google-fu.

Answer (score 42):

It's a thoughtful proposal, but I'm pretty indifferent.

The value gained, it seems to me, is just a few seconds saved per added MDN link. (Or Python docs link, or Microsoft docs link, or whatever, if this were to be expanded to other docs sites.)

The *downside* is that you've then made it easier for people to insert links to documentation they haven't even looked at. This is *already* a problem, and is the flipside of the common Meta gripe about question askers not Googling before asking: pretty much every *good* question asker on Stack Overflow has had the experience of asking a thoughtful question about some nuance of an API's behaviour that is not described in the docs, only to have some *total dick* come along and post *"You should Google before asking next time! Read the docs at http://example.com/docs/useless-page-that-doesnt-help-at-all."* So when you post a proposal that amounts to *"Make it more convenient to post documentation links without even having to open the target page in your browser first to copy the URL"*... well, it makes me a little *nervous* about the effect it's going to have on the relevance of documentation links that get included in answers.

The act of actually opening a docs page and copying the link is usually a small proportion of the time I expend per docs link in an answer. I'm probably also making decisions about what the right source to link to is (e.g. in the case of web stuff, should I be citing MDN or is this the sort of weird edge-casey question where I shouldn't be trusting MDN and should be directly citing the specification? Or in the case of Python, should I be linking to https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader or to https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader or to https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader?), and looking over the docs to see if there's a particular subsection that's most relevant that I should be linking to, and maybe copying a quote from the docs into my answer and spending the next minute fidgeting with formatting to make it look like it does on the docs page. Making the *act of inserting the link* marginally quicker just doesn't really register as an important possible timesaver, for me.

Even if I could snap my fingers and cause this feature to exist tomorrow, with no development effort required by anybody, I'm on the fence about whether I'd want to, because of the points above. If it means spending dev time that could be spent on something else, then I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: Entirely agreed, I am myself guilty of not re-read entirely the MDN docs I point to every time because my browser already offers me history based url auto-completion (which achieves exactly the same purpose as this PR, but to pages I at least visited once), to find out my memory had a bias or that the article had been updated.

Comment: Not to mention that it would be even harder to explain that link-only answers are bad if we gave specific tooling that helps include links in answers...

Comment: @AndrasDeak apparently, that wasn't a problem for Docs.SO

Comment: Personally, I find even [trivial find-docs-link helper scripts useful](https://gist.github.com/zed/8aad60cf66392f13e3e27c9ffd2c67a3)

Comment: @AndrasDeak SO already provides a UI for inserting a hyperlink while still discouraging link-only answers; I think that is because you insert a hyperlink via the toolbar, so it is parallel to bold, italics, quotes, which are just formatting tools, not methods for creating a complete answer (nobody thinks to put a bold-only or quote-only answer...). The proposed UI would integrate into the existing **Insert hyperlink** functionality, and would not be immediately visible; so I don't think this UI would encourage link-only answers.